# Database speed depends columns or rows (records)?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an student entity, now I want to create a student table and a student attribute table like `dob, age, salary`. Students attributes are approximately 120.

So which will better in future for table performance and my MySQL manipulation

Options

1. Create one table (student_mst) with all the student attributes as columns with good datatypes
2. OR, create two tables (`student_mst, student_attributes`) with relation and add multiple records of student attribute in `table - student_attributes.`

Answer (score 1):

These are two completely different approaches, so it depends entirely how you want to work with the data. The performance is only an issue if you pick a model that doesn't work well with how you want to access the data.

The first option is the natural approach if all students use all or most of the attributes, and if there is a fixed set of attributes.

The second option would be useful if students have different sets of attributes, and you are likely to expand the set of attributes.

With the first approach you typically write different queries to work with different attributes. It's for example easy to get a list of students and return a few attributes. Example:

```
 select StudentId, Name, Age, Class, Grade
 from Students
 order by Age desc
```

With the second approach you would typically get the basic student information and the student attributes separately. To get a list of students with some attributes would be more complicated, and it builds up the more attributes you want to get. Example:

```
 select s.StudentId, Name = a1.Value, Age = a2.Value, Class = a3.Value, Grade = a4.Value
 from Students s
 inner join Attributes a1 on a1.StudentId = s.StudentId
 inner join Attributes a2 on a2.StudentId = s.StudentId
 inner join Attributes a2 on a3.StudentId = s.StudentId
 inner join Attributes a3 on a4.StudentId = s.StudentId
 order by cast(a.Value as int) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the expensive operation in relational databases is recovering the "lines" of the dataset. Being able to filter also by column comes as a syntactic sugar to better tune your final dataset. Hence, try to optimise the way you arrange your relation between the lines, and dont care too much about the number of column as it doesnt have an influence on the search performance, but mainly on the amount of data that will travel "on the wire" .

Answer (score 0):

Some more considerations on top of the answer by @Guffa

If you do go for the related attributes table. Every attribute for each student is going to cost you an attribute id and a student id, say 8 bytes if they were integers, so how sparse they are is worth thinking about.

Can the 120 attributes be grouped, might be worth looking at. Perhaps an attribute type /group and some 1 - 1 extension tables.

If you are just getting a student and all their attributes versus all the students with an attribute.

If there are very few attributes you are planning on querying, an xml snippet, or a serialised object for the rest is worth a look.

Lastly the complex join query (wouldn't want to do 120 of them :) )

You could pivot them instead, or you could get them back with one join as two columns, that would have a definite impact on how you mapped them to say the UI though.

There's no right answer to this, but it's not really one you have to set in stone in your design if you hide the schema behind some methods instead of splattering SQL all over it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are better off letting the column composition of tables be driven by the logical structure of the data, and relying on physical design features such as indexes to help you speed things up.

Whether an attribute of a student belongs in your student table is mostly a question of whether all students have this attribute, or only some students.  If all students have the attribute, keeping the attribute in the student table is usually going to be faster than doing joins at retrieval time.  It's also the logical approach.

If, on the other hand, you have attributes that only pertain to certain students, then you need to analyze the case to see whether you are dealing with specialized subsets of the students.  If this is indeed the case, then you need to look up "ER Specializaton" to see how this can be modeled at the conceptual level.

If you want to see how a relational design can implement a case of specialization, look up "class table inheritance".